# DirectShow loop video infinitely with C++

Tags: c++, video, delay, directshow, infinite-loop

I have this small C++ code playing a video clip with **DirectShow**. What I want is the video to never stop so once it reaches the end I set the position to 0 again. The problem is that between the end and the start of the new loop there's a small **delay** that I would like to remove. My code looks like this:

```
#define WM_GRAPHNOTIFY  WM_USER

// Global vars
IGraphBuilder*      g_pGraphBuilder;
IMediaControl*      g_pMediaCtrl;
IMediaPosition*     g_pMediaPos;
IMediaEventEx*      g_pMediaEvent;

HWND                h_MainWindow;

// PlayVideo() - I removed the errors checking lines (irrelevant right now)
RECT grc;
IVideoWindow *pVidWin = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_FilterGraph, 
    NULL, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IGraphBuilder,
    (void**)&g_pGraphBuilder
);

hr = g_pGraphBuilder->RenderFile(L"Clip.mpeg", NULL);
hr = g_pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void **)&pVidWin);
hr = pVidWin->put_Owner((OAHWND)h_MainWindow);
hr = pVidWin->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);

GetClientRect(h_MainWindow, &grc);
pVidWin->SetWindowPosition(0, 0, grc.right, grc.bottom);

hr = g_pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEventEx, (void **)&g_pMediaEvent);
hr = g_pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaPosition, (void**)&g_pMediaPos);
hr = g_pMediaEvent->SetNotifyWindow((OAHWND)h_MainWindow, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, 0);
g_pMediaEvent->SetNotifyFlags(0);

hr = g_pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&g_pMediaCtrl);
g_pMediaCtrl->Run();

// WndPrc of the main window, the WM_GRAPHNOTIFY message
long EventCode, Param1, Param2;
// ...
case WM_GRAPHNOTIFY:
    while (g_pMediaEvent->GetEvent(&EventCode, &Param1, &Param2, 0)!=E_ABORT) {
        switch (EventCode) {
            case EC_COMPLETE:
                // Going back to the start of the clip
                g_pMediaPos->put_CurrentPosition(0);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }   
        g_pMediaEvent->FreeEventParams(EventCode, Param1, Param2);
    }
break;
// ...
```

The problem here, as I said, is that there's a noticeable lag when the video stops and starts again. It looks like EC_COMPLETE is not sent exactly when the video stops or maybe it is but `put_CurrentPosition()` takes some time to set the position back to 0. Anyway, the problem is that and I wonder if there's a solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard solution for looped playback, yet the task is not impossible and is doable with reasonable effort.

The wrong way is to achieve the desired behavior with standard graph/pipeline expecting some magic to perform a seamless seek operation on the upstream part of the graph. The graph streams data in a very efficient way and preloads the pipeline to play data accurately. However once you reached the end of the file, there is inevitable seek and state transition which involves a delay

You need either of the two (both approaches require development effort):

1. a smart custom filter which intercepts completion (end of stream) message and seeks the upstream part, or in case of small stream, buffers data entirely and continues seamlessly from internal buffer (good for small streams)
2. a two-graph design where one part is reading from file and sending data to another graph for playback, and the other graph handling endless playback from injected data; you can seek first graph normally without delay propagating to the other graph

**Update.** Since the media file is short (sort of animation perhaps), the item #1 above looks applicable. The goal is that buffering filter accepts everything up to completion, keeps this on internal buffer, and streams further from internal buffer.

- Source -> ... (demultiplexer etc) -> **Buffer** -> Decompressor -> Video Renderer
- Source -> ... (demultiplexer etc) -> Decompressor -> **Buffer** -> Video Renderer

Both options achieve the goal and you choose between the two depending on memory/speed requirements and preferences.

The best base for the Buffer filter is [`CBaseFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Roman. My file is only 4 Mb so I would like to create a buffer and seek to it just when EC_COMPLETE occurs. I suppose this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758088(v=vs.85).aspx has enough information to guide me through this.

Comment: Source filter does not let you accept input. You need simply custom filter derived from `CBaseFilter`, see my update above. As I said there are many ways to do it, my point is that the way I suggested is actually the easiest.

Comment: Thanks again. Well, it's just a simple animation and it doesn't need any control or input. It just plays until the window is closed.

Comment: Yeah, so you accept frames 0, 1, ... N and on the output pin you stream  them 0, 1, ... N, and then frame 0 again as N+1 and so on. Same data, just new timestamps.